# Copy partial row when target column is changed to specific text

Tags: excel, vba

**Summary:**

I have two sheets in the same workbook that I need to move data between, from Physician_Orders to DME_Orders, when specific text is entered into Column I of Physician_Orders.

**Some details:**

- Each sheet has columns A:I
- When Physician_Orders Column I is changed to the text, "Rx Received" I need the data in Columns A:C to be copied to the first empty row of Columns A:C on DME_Orders, leaving the data on Physician Orders intact.

**I would be okay if this occurs in one of two ways:**

- To occur immediately upon the change happening
- To occur only when a button is pressed

I've tried about five different scripts I've found on SO, but I'm getting errors with every one of them.  My current mess looks like this, which gives me the error, "Object required."

```
Sub RxRCVD()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim destRng As Range
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("I2:I500")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value = "Rx Received" Then

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     With Sheets("DME_Orders")
        Set destRng = .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)

         Sheets("Physician_Orders").Range("A:C" & Target.Address.Row).Copy Destination:=destRng

            .Columns("A:C").AutoFit
     End With
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm really new to VBA - what do you mean worksheet change event? @urdearboy

Comment: Are you trying to have this macro fire automatically when someone changes a cell in `Range("I2:I500")`? Also, your copy statement is wrong. Are you trying to copy one row? You have `Range("A:C#)` when you need `Range("A#:C#)`

Comment: What are you trying to copy? THe entire row of the changed cell? Or an entire range?

Comment: I'd like it to fire automatically when someone changes a cell in Range("I2:I500")

Comment: Need to copy the range A:C in the row of the changed cell @urdearboy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `Worksheet_Change` event to automatically trigger your macro
2. You can reshape the range you want to copy based off the `Target` by using `Offset` and `Resize`
3. Toggle off events to avoid a infinite loop and your instance of excel crashing. It doesn't look like this will trigger a infinite loop but it's best practice

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim DME As Worksheet: Set DME = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DME_Orders")
Dim lr As Long

If Not Intersect(Range("I2:I500"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "Rx Received" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            lr = DME.Range("A" & DME.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            Target.Offset(, -8).Resize(1, 3).Copy
            DME.Range("A" & lr).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            DME.Columns("A:C").AutoFit

        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I ran into a snag.  Bottom line, I think I need to only have this script fire on a button press instead of on a worksheet_change.  How much different would this script need to be?